# Facebook PHP SDK Birthday APP using FQL

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm a newbie in PHP programming. I use a FQL query to get birthdays of all user's friends.
But I want to sort the users according to month and day. Can this be possible in multidimensional arrays? I want:

```
$year = array('jan' => array('1' => array(data returned by fql query), '2' => array(data returned by fql query),..etc), 'feb' =>  array('1' => array(data returned by fql query)), 'mar' => array(), etc);
```

Is it possible?
My code so far:

```
$query = "SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, pic_square, current_location, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date";

$year =array();
$prm  =   array(
          'method'    => 'fql.query',       
          'query'     => $query,
          'callback'  => ''     
          );



$friends  =  $facebook->api($prm);

for($m = 1;$m <= 12;$m++){
    $dm = mktime(0,0,0,$m,26);
    $dm = date("M", $dm);
    $year[] = $dm;

    for($d = 1;$d <= 31;$d++){
        $a2 = array($d => array());
        $a3 = $out[$dm];
        array_push($out,array($dm => array($d => "")));
    }                   
}
```

PS: I want to be able to represent birthdays in each month in a div, order by day of month.
Thanks.

Comment: why you dont want to use order by clause?

Answer (score 1):

multi_sort($myArray[index], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC)  is what you are looking for, and you can get rid of the nested for loops.  pass the array and index to be sorted by, sort numerically, and in SORT_ASC, or SORT_DESC depending on what you want.  You may need to removed dashes or slashes from the dates first, experiment and find out.

Here is the PHP man page.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make the day/month an array key and sort based one that:

```
$sort = array();
foreach($friends as $friend)
{
    // note the extra 0's here, to give us padding to filter out duplicate array keys
    // this gives us an int in the format 030100, 093100, etc
    $key = (int)date('Md00', strtotime($friend['birthday_date']));

    // make sure we don't have duplicates...if the key already exists, incrememnt it by one
    while(isset($sort[$key])) $key++;

    $sort[$key] = $friend;
}

// sort the items by array key
ksort($sort);

// $sort now contains your friends, sorted by birthday.
```

Note that as mentioned, facebook allows you do do the sorting on their end, so it's best to let them do the work. There are some cases where post-query sorting is very useful, and this is generally how I like to do it.